# what's difference between 'delete' and 'remove' in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am learning Elisp by reading others' code. Then I found people use both `delete` and `remove` to delete element from sequence. I checked the document and the code of `remove` it seams just a wrapper for `delete` which when the sequence is a list, do a `copy-sequence`.

Is it really matter to copy list to do the `delete`? Or I can just use `delete` which is a `C` command which should be more efficient I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`remove` returns

> a copy of seq with all occurrences of elt removed.

whereas `delete`

> delete[s] by side effect any occurrences of elt as a member of seq.

so it modifies the original sequence. (Unless the first element is a hit, so pleasee consult <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> delete for full details.)